# how to format string(numbers) printing in javascript

Tags: javascript, string-formatting

For example. I want to print numbers from 1 to 20

but I want print 1 as `01` , 2 as `02` and so on ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
formatNumber = function( num )
{
  if ( num < 10 )
  {
    return "0" + num;
  }
  else
  {
    return "" + num;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is shorter version:

```
leadingZero = function(num){
    return (num < 10) ? "0"+num : num;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a generic 'zeroPad' function for you:

```
function zeroPad(nr,base){
        base = base || 10;
        var  len = (String(base).length - String(nr).length)+1;
        return len > 0 ? new Array(len).join('0')+nr : nr;
}
//usage
zeroPad(5);       //=> "05"
zeroPad(50,1000); //=> "0050"
zeroPad(50);      //=> "50"
```

or as Number Extension:

```
Number.prototype.zeroPad = Number.prototype.zeroPad ||
    function(base){
            base = base || 10;
            var  len = (String(base).length - String(this).length)+1;
            return len > 0 ? new Array(len).join('0')+this : this;
};
//usage
(5).zeroPad();      //=> "05"
(50).zeroPad(1000); //=> "0050"
(50).zeroPad();     //=> "50"
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's abuse the ternary operator:

```
for(var n = 1; n <= 20; n++) {
    console.log((n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.prototype.padStart`:

```js
`${num}`.padStart(2, '0');
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart):

> The `padStart()` method pads the current string with another string (repeated, if needed) so that the resulting string reaches the given length. The padding is applied from the start (left) of the current string.

`padStart` is only defined on strings—not numbers—so you need to cast the number to string (`num.toString()`; or more idiomatically `` `${num}` ``) before you call `padStart`. The first parameter is the minimum length of the outcome string so if you numbers reach the hundreds do `` `${num}`.padStart(3, '0') ``.

```js
// Create an array of the numbers 1 through 20.
const arr = Array.from({ length: 20 }, (_, i) => i + 1);

arr.forEach(i => {
  // Pad each one digit number with a leading zero.
  console.log(`${i}`.padStart(2, '0'));
})
```